# Can you share items between workshops?

Tags: fallout-4

I swear I read an ingame hint that said Workshops would share my stuff between them, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I have a settlement at Sanctuary and Red Rocket Truck Stop, but I can't access my items I added in Sanctuary at RRTS. Am I mistaken in remembering that you could do this, or is there something I need to do to get that to work?

Comment: FYI: The in-game tip about Workshops sharing stuff between them is probably referring to crafting stations within a single settlement. All crafting stations within one settlement have a shared supply pool. Store supplies in one station, and they're instantly available for use (or transfer out of) all other stations in the same settlement. Sharing between settlements is a whole different matter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can - in order to do so you must the Local Leader perk at level 1 and have a spare settler and use that settler to set up a supply line. Enter Workshop mode and select the spare settler and press the highlighted button for Supply Line:

[image: supply line option in workshop mode]

This provides you with a list of your eligible settlements to set up a supply line with:

[image: supply lines configuration list]

All supply lines are visible from the map:

[image: pip boy map showing supply lines]

Comment: I don't see the supply line option. Is there a perk as a requirement? Local Leader maybe? (I don't have that yet.)

Comment: -1. I can't approve of reposting your answer instead of pointing OP to the other question.